# Is there a specific jquery method for doing something while ajax is loading?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a comment system, where if you submit a comment, it is appended to the `#comment` div via ajax. I want a 'loader' spinner gif to display while the page is waiting for the request to be completed. At this point, what I've managed to do is add a `#load` div at the end of `#comments`, containing the spinner. Using jquery, I hide `#load` right off the bat. When the "post comment" button is clicked, `#load` is shown with jquery, and then my ajax request contains code to hide it again. This way, the spinner displays when I submit the comment, and disappears when the ajax finally arrives and the comment is displayed.

But my method seems very round-about. I feel like there has to be a simpler solution, some method built into jquery. Is there?

Comment: Set the background to have the spinner.gif? Also, look into beforeSend?

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question

Comment: I don't believe there is anything built in to do it automatically.  You would just use the "complete" callback to hide the spinner, or remove it or whatever.

Comment: That's exactly how I'd do it, besides having the `#load` div contain`style="display:none"` on the original page. There is a way to track progress with jQuery though, which you can see an example of here: http://pastebin.com/tws8Q9ud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can attach  `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` to your loading div. These functions get triggered for every ajax call.

```
$('#loading').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
 });
```

if you plan taking the route of showing your loading div before the ajax call and hiding it during success, be aware that not every ajax request will end successfully. It can time out and your loading div will stay visible then. It's best to hide the spinner in the `always()` function:

```
$('#loading').show() //show spinner
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
    $('#loading').hide();//hide your spinner here!!
});
```

Comment: Caution: This method gets call for every ajax call on the page, even if there is an ajax call that you want to run behind the scenes like triggering to get a stack of image loaded to your dom.

Comment: yes, `ajaxSend()` and  `ajaxComplete()` may be a better option

Comment: Why won't every ajax request end successfully?

Comment: Like I said, a request can time out because of  numerous reasons. For example the server is off line or unable to respond.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any such method built into jquery.

If you really hate your method for some reason, and if you're using jquery to submit the comment, you could do something like this:

```
$("#comments").append("<div id="loading">loading...</div>");
//submit comment
```

And then in the ajax request:

```
$("#loading").remove();
//append the comment
```

But honestly, your solution seems cleaner. This is just another option. Is there a specific reason you want to use a built-in jquery method?